# How modify API request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api

***I have few React Components :***

**Main.jsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { Preloader } from "../Preloader";
import { Pokemons } from "../Pokemons";

function Main() {
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(function getPokemons() {
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20")
      .then((responce) => responce.json())
      .then((data) => {
        data.results && setPokemons(data.results);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className="container content">
      {loading ? <Preloader /> : <Pokemons pokemons={pokemons} />}
    </main>
  );
}

export { Main };
```

**Pokemon.jsx**

```
function Pokemon(props) {
  const { name: name, url: url } = props;

 
  return (
    <ul className="collection with-header">
      <li className="collection-header">
        <h4>{name}</h4>
      </li>
      <li className="collection-item"></li>
      <li className="collection-item">{url}</li>
    </ul>
  );
}

export { Pokemon };
```

**Pokemons.jsx**

```
import { Pokemon } from "./Pokemon";

function Pokemons(props) {
  const { pokemons = [] } = props;

  if (!pokemons.length) {
    return <h4 className="pokemons_error">Nothing found</h4>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="pokemons">
      {pokemons.map((pokemon, id) => (
        <Pokemon key={id} {...pokemon} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export { Pokemons };
```

**Thanks to fetch in main.jsx, I get twenty objects (Pokémon) with their unique name and a link to the characteristics (each has its own):**

[index.html (png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WqXS.png)

***If you go to any of these links (This is an Api request), you can see many characteristics of the Pokémon:***

[Example.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifJZh.png)

***From this data, I need to get the height, weight, sprite,type of each pokemon instead of links in index.html***

***HOW? Help me...***

*API : https://pokeapi.co/*

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `Pokemon.jsx` like this:

```js
function Pokemon(props) {
  const { name, height, weight, sprites, types } = props;
  const sprite = sprites.front_default; // you can select on of sprites
  const type = types[0].type; // just taking the first type

 
  return (
    <ul className="collection with-header">
      <li className="collection-header">
        <h4>{name}</h4>
      </li>
      <li className="collection-item"></li>
      <li className="collection-item">{height}</li>
      <li className="collection-item">{weight}</li>
      <li className="collection-item">
        <img src={sprite} />
      </li>
      <li className="collection-item">{type}</li>
    </ul>
  );
}

export { Pokemon };
```